# How to increment counter in django templates

Tags: python, django, for-loop, counting

I am trying to get the total count of infringements for each infringer. The counter is not incrementing. ( {{ a|add:"1" }} ) It outputs 1 1 1 instead of total of 3. Please assist.

> ```
> {% for infringer in page_obj %}   
> <tr>   
>  <td>{{infringer.id}}</td>  
>  <td>{{infringer.created|date:"d M, Y"}}</td>  
>  <td>{{infringer.name}}</td>   
>  <td>{{infringer.brand_name}}</td>  
>  <td>{{infringer.status}}</td>   
>  <td>   
> {% with a=0 %}
>
>   {% for i in inc %}   
>      {% if infringer.id == i.infringer.id %}
>         {{ a|add:"1" }}
>
>
>       {% endif %}
>   {% endfor %}    
> {% endwith %}
> ```

views.py

> ```
> @login_required(login_url='login') 
> def infringerlist(request):
>    q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else '' 
>    ings= Infringer.objects.filter(Q(created__icontains=q) | Q(id__icontains=q) | 
>    Q(status__name__icontains=q) |
>    Q(brand_name__icontains=q) | Q(name__icontains=q),
> customer=request.user.customer,)
> paginator = Paginator(ings, 10)
> page_number = request.GET.get('page')
> page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
> inc = Infringement.objects.filter(customer=request.user.customer)
>    context= {'page_obj': page_obj, 'inc': inc}
>    return render(request,'base/infringers_list.html', context)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Templates are *not* supposed to have business logic. Neither should they change state. These should simply *render* the data.

You can count the number of infrigments, and then pass it to the context:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def infringerlist(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else ''
    ings = Infringer.objects.filter(
        Q(created__icontains=q)
        | Q(id__icontains=q)
        | Q(status__name__icontains=q)
        | Q(brand_name__icontains=q)
        | Q(name__icontains=q),
        customer__user=request.user,
    )
    paginator = Paginator(ings, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    infrigments = Infringement.objects.filter(customer__user=request.user).count()
    return render(
        request,
        'base/infringers_list.html',
        context={'page_obj': page_obj, 'infrigments': infrigments},
    )
```

and render it with `{{ infrigments }}`.

Comment: Thanks but this gives me the total count all the infringements. I wants the total count of infringements for each infringer as I go through the for loop.   Anyway to add this in the view?

Comment: any help on this unresolved issue?

Comment: @Farid: count by what *key*? Your templates seems to count the total infrigments, not per something...